# MySQL Select where number IN column

Tags: php, mysql

I need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE '123' IN (`column`)
```

In 'column' (varchar 255 field) there are some numbers like 1, 50, 145, 123, 58,

I don't know to explain better, but I think you understand what I need.

Comment: find_in_set('123',column) (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) or normalise your data properly

Comment: post what you have tried??

Comment: Are the numbers 1,50,145... one-per-row? Or is the 'column' field in each row a string containing all the numbers?

Comment: @Osiris, numbers are in one row, 'column` field containing all these numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('123', column);
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: Thank you, but works fine only if I search first number on all these numbers. I have all these numbers in one field (name here 'column'). These numbers are in one row, column = 1, 50, 145, 123, 58, in this example.

Comment: To clarify, your field 'column' is "1,50,145,123,58". You are searching this column for the occurrence of X which could be any of these numbers right?

Comment: You field 'column' needs to be of type SET.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%123%';
```

Comment: Thank you, but for example if I search 123 but there is a number like 1234, will return wrong result, I need to search exactly for 123 number between all these numbers

Comment: Oh. Then if you cannot use the other SET suggestion, you must split the `column` result somewhere along the line and test them. If you use LIKE to return a set with some extra rows, your post processing may be easy with PHP, or you will have to write a function in MySQL to do that for your. I'm sorry but I have not time to make it now. Here is a fine beginning example.[http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/]

Answer (score 1):

try [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE find_in_set('123',column)`

Comment: Thank you, but works fine only if I search first number on all these numbers.

Comment: @Bogdan have you tried it .. this should irrespective of position

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN ('123');
```